# php laravel blade (view returning wrong)

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

View
[image]

Why is my view showing like that? I altereted a file that was edit.blade.php, i did 0 alterations in create.blade.php, and now the view is returning like that, i will provide the code to anyone who could help me find out why is behaving like this, tahnk you;

there are two files i will gladly provide

i tried even turning the project back to what it was some time ago in git hub, even THIS did not work

```
    '@extends('templates.crud',["current" => "controle"])

@section('body')

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h5>Descontos</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">Perfil</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Descontos</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        @if($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
          </div>
        @endif

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form id="formulario" action="{{ route('descontos/store') }}"
                        class="form-horizontal" method="POST">

                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="login" id="login" value="{{Auth::user()->login}}">
                        <input type="hidden" id="contratos_id" name="contratos_id" value="{{ $contrato }}">
                        <input type="hidden" id="clientes_id" name="clientes_id" value="{{ $cliente->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" id="matricula" name="matricula" value="{{ $matricula }}">

                        <div class="form-row" style="padding-top: 10px">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="contribuicoes_tipos_id" style="font-weight: bold">Tipo</label>
                                <select class="chosen-select form-control {{ $errors->has('contribuicoes_tipos_id') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    id="contribuicoes_tipos_id" name="contribuicoes_tipos_id">
                                    <option value="Selecione...">Selecione...</option>

                                    @if(!isset($tipoSelecionado))
                                        @foreach($contribuicoesTipo as $list)
                                            <option value="{{ $list->id }}"
                                                    {{ $list->id == old('contribuicoes_tipos_id') ? 'selected' : ''}}
                                            >{{ $list->descricao }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @else
                                        @foreach($contribuicoesTipo as $list)
                                            <option value="{{ $list->id }}"
                                                    {{ $list->id == $tipoSelecionado ? 'selected' : ''}}
                                            >{{ $list->descricao }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif

                                </select>

                                @if($errors->has('contribuicoes_tipos_id'))
                                    <div class=" {{$errors->has('contribuicoes_tipos_id') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{$errors->first('contribuicoes_tipos_id')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="motivos">
                                <label for="motivos_id" style="font-weight: bold">Motivo</label>
                                <select class="form-control {{ $errors->has('motivo_id') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="motivo_id" name="motivo_id">
                                    <option value="Selecione...">Selecione...</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="diretores_id" style="font-weight: bold">Diretor</label>
                                <select class="chosen-select form-control {{ $errors->has('diretores_id') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    id="diretores_id" name="diretores_id">
                                    <option value="Selecione...">Selecione...</option>

                                    @if(!isset($diretorSelecionado))
                                        @foreach($diretores as $list)
                                            <option value="{{ $list->id }}" {{ $list->id == old('diretores_id') ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $list->nome }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @else
                                        @foreach($diretores as $list)
                                            <option value="{{ $list->id }}" {{ $list->id == $diretorSelecionado ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $list->nome }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>

                                @if($errors->has('diretores_id'))
                                    <div class=" {{$errors->has('diretores_id') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{$errors->first('diretores_id')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label>Início</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('inicio') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="inicio" id="inicio" value="{{ old('inicio') }}">

                                @if($errors->first('inicio'))
                                    <div class=" {{ $errors->has('inicio') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{ $errors->first('inicio')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label>Fim</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('fim') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fim" id="fim" value="{{ old('fim') }}">

                                @if($errors->first('fim'))
                                    <div class=" {{ $errors->has('fim') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{ $errors->first('fim')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label for="valor" style="font-weight: bold">Valor</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control money {{ $errors->has('valor') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="valor" id="valor"
                                    value="{{ old('valor') }}">

                                @if($errors->has('valor'))
                                    <div class=" {{$errors->has('valor') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{$errors->first('valor')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                                <label>Observação</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('observacao') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="observacao" id="observacao" value="{{ old('observacao') }}">

                                @if($errors->first('observacao'))
                                    <div class=" {{ $errors->has('observacao') ? 'invalid-feedback' : ''}}">
                                        {{ $errors->first('observacao')}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-row mt-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="salvar" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Salvar</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-2" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold"
                            onclick="window.location.href='/perfil/descontos/{{ encrypt($clienteId) }}/{{encrypt($matricula)}}'">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


@endsection('body')

  

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#motivos").hide();
        $("#contribuicoes_tipos_id").on("change", function(){
            $("#motivo_id option").remove();
            if($("#contribuicoes_tipos_id").val() == 63) { //Taxa administrativa
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 1, text: 'Promoção'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 2, text: 'Carência'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 3, text: 'Gerência'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 4, text: 'Maior Idade'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 5, text: 'Óbito'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 9, text: 'Migração - Categoria'}));
                $("#motivos").show('slow');
                $("#motivo_id").focus();
            } else if($("#contribuicoes_tipos_id").val() == 73) { //Débitos anteriores
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 8, text: 'Desligado até 2 anos'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 7, text: 'Desligado de 2 a 4 anos'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 6, text: 'Desligado a mais de 5 anos'}));
                $("#motivo_id").append($('<option>', { value: 3, text: 'Gerência'}));
                $("#motivos").show('slow');
                $("#motivo_id").focus();
            } else {
                $("#motivos").hide('slow');
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
@endsection('scripts')

the controllers of the area:
```

```
    Route::prefix('descontos')->group(function (){
        Route::get('/index/{clienteId}', 'DescontosController@index')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/index');
        Route::get('/create/{clienteId}', 'DescontosController@create')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/create');
        Route::post('/store', 'DescontosController@store')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/store');
        Route::get('/edit/{descontoId}', 'DescontosController@edit')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/edit');
        Route::get('/delete/{descontoId}', 'DescontosController@destroy')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/delete');
        Route::get('/clear/{descontoId}', 'DescontosController@clear')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/clear');
        Route::post('/update', 'DescontosController@update')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/update');
        Route::get('/calcular-percentual', 'DescontosController@calcularPercentual')->middleware('can:Controle')->name('descontos/calcular-percentual');
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (Gate::denies('Controle'))
            return redirect('/app');

        DB::beginTransaction(); //Start transaction!

        try {
            $request->validate([
                'diretores_id' => 'required|not_in:' . "Selecione...",
                'clientes_id' => 'required',
                'contribuicoes_tipos_id' => 'required|not_in:' . "Selecione...",
                'valor' => [
                    new ValorDesconto(),
                    'required'],

                'inicio' => 'required',
                'fim' => 'required',
                'observacao' => 'max:180'
            ]);

            $clientesId = $request->input('clientes_id');
            $tipo = $request->input('contribuicoes_tipos_id');
            $contratoId = $request->input('contratos_id');
            $valor =  (double)str_replace(',', '.', $request->valor);


            $desconto = new Descontos();

            $desconto->diretores_id = $request->input('diretores_id');
            $desconto->contratos_id = $contratoId;
            $desconto->clientes_id = $clientesId;
            $desconto->contribuicoes_tipos_id = $tipo;
            $desconto->valor = $valor;
            $desconto->inicio = $request->input('inicio');
            $desconto->fim = $request->input('fim');
            $desconto->observacao = $request->input('observacao');
            $desconto->login = Auth::user()->login;
            if($request->input('motivo_id')) {
                $desconto->descontos_motivos_id = $request->input('motivo_id');
            }
            
            $desconto->save();

            $this->aplicarDescontoContribuicoes($contratoId, $clientesId, $tipo, $request->input('inicio'), $request->input('fim') );

            DB::commit();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            //failed logic here
            DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }

        return redirect('/perfil/descontos' . '/' .  encrypt($clientesId)  . '/' .  encrypt($request->matricula) );
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Are you using `dd()` or `var_dump()` anywhere, even in the controller?

Comment: _"i will provide the code to anyone who could help me"_ - Sharing the code is a _prerequisite_ for us to be able to help.

Comment: it does not contain any dd or var dump, i checked even the controllers, the php artisan view: clear, did not work too

Comment: Can you show your controller as well?

Comment: sure, sorry, im a junior and my senior is sick

Comment: That's the routes. Can you show the contents of `DescontosController@store`?

Comment: did you mean whats inside the: DescontosController.php?

Comment: Yes, specifically the `store` function

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause it. It's not getting to the bottom of the function, which has a redirect, because the URL still has the `store` route. You might have to dig through the other functions called within the store function. I can tell you it's not the view, though, because it's not getting that far.

Comment: it was a dd in the controller, hiden. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check is you have any dd() in your blade file. If you don't have one, you can try to clear the view cache by running the following php artisan view:clear

Comment: it does not contain any dd or var dump, i checked even the controllers, the php artisan view: clear, did not work too